# HTML & CSS works in the development mode but CSS is missing in the production mode

Tags: html, css, node.js, express, webpack-4

I am completely new in this field.I apologize for any mistakes. I am working on a node js project using webpack, HTML loader. I am using dev server dependency to test in the localhost. All the models and views and the template index.html files are located in the 'src' folder. The webpack config and package json and the server.js files are located in the root directory. The webpack HTML loader is used to load index.html file in the 'dist' folder. In the 'dist' folder, there is a folder called css and inside of it style.css is located. 
Everything works in the development mode and I can run the page in my localhost but problem starts when I try to run "npm run start" which actually includes "node server.js". And then when I try to access the page in the localhost then the styling of the page does not work but the interactive behavior of the page works fine. I think, the 'href' that links the css in the index.htm file is not correct.
Does anybody have idea what is wrong in my code? I have attached all the images and code that I am using.

[image: src folder]

[image: dist folder]

webpack.config.js

```
const path = require('path');
const HtmlWebpackPlugin = require('html-webpack-plugin');
module.exports = {
    entry: ['./src/js/index.js'],
    output: {
        path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'dist'),
        filename: 'js/bundle.js'
    },
    devServer:{
        contentBase: './dist'
    },
    plugins: [
        new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
            filename: 'index.html',
            template: './src/index.html'
        })
    ],
    module: {
        rules: [
            {
                test: /\.js$/,
                exclude: /node_modules/,
                use:{
                    loader: 'babel-loader'
                }
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

package.json file

```
{
  "name": "forkify",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "dev": "webpack --mode development",
    "dev-start": "webpack-dev-server --mode development --open",
    "heroku-postbuild": "webpack --mode production",
    "start": "node server.js"
  },
  "author": "Sayeedur Rahman",
  "license": "ISC",
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.9.0",
    "@babel/preset-env": "^7.9.5",
    "babel-loader": "^8.1.0",
    "html-webpack-plugin": "^4.2.0",
    "webpack": "^4.20.2",
    "webpack-cli": "^3.1.1",
    "webpack-dev-server": "^3.10.3"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "axios": "^0.19.2",
    "core-js": "^3.6.5",
    "express": "^4.17.1",
    "fractional": "^1.0.0",
    "regenerator-runtime": "^0.13.5",
    "uniqid": "^5.2.0"
  },
  "engines": {
    "node": "12.16.1",
    "npm": "6.13.4"
  }
}
```

server.js file

```
const express = require('express');
const path = require('path');
const port = process.env.PORT || 8080;
const app = express();

app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/dist'));

app.get('/', (req, res) =>{
    res.sendFile(path.resolve(__dirname, '/dist', 'index.html'))
});

app.listen(port);
console.log(`server started on ${port}`);
```

index.html file  section

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Nunito+Sans:400,600,700" rel="stylesheet">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">
    <link rel="shortcut icon" href="img/favicon.png" type="image/x-icon">
    <title>forkify // Search over 1,000,000 recipes</title>
</head>
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if this works but try adding this line after your routes in the server.js file:

```
app.use(express.static(path.resolve(__dirname, './dist')));
```

Also note the dot befor /dist

If this doesn't work try changing the following line in your index.html:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="../../css/style.css">
```

or

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="../css/style.css">
```